# How can I force content within modal to be 100% the height of the modal?

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

I am trying to use flexbox to make the content within a Modalize view go to 100% of the Modal view. Currently, it's only going to the height of the content, and not the modal.

With this code:

```
 <Modalize
        // onOpen={onOpen}
        onOpened={() => console.log("ONOPEN")}
        ref={modalizeRef}
        modalStyle={{ flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          shadowColor: '#000', shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 6 }, shadowOpacity: 0.45, shadowRadius: 16,
        }}
        alwaysOpen={85}
        handlePosition="inside"
      >
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
        <Text>
          Data here
        </Text>
      </View>
    </Modalize>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

How can I make it so the green background fills the entire height of the modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Use `Dimensions` to set the height.

**Sample Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/sadistic-waffles)**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';

const window = Dimensions.get('screen');

export default function App() {
  const modalizeRef = React.useRef();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Modalize
        // onOpen={onOpen}
        onOpened={() => console.log('ONOPEN')}
        ref={modalizeRef}
        modalStyle={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          shadowColor: '#000',
          shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 6 },
          shadowOpacity: 0.45,
          shadowRadius: 16,
        }}
        alwaysOpen={85}
        handlePosition="inside">
        <View style={{ height: window.height * 0.85, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
          <Text>Data here</Text>
        </View>
      </Modalize>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: That would always present the modal with scroll, as it the modal would always be shorter than the height. Otherwise, would have to manage if it's open or not (as this modal could be partially open like a bottom sheet or open to around 85% fullscreen). Is there no way to do it without presenting it a height?

Comment: I tried ```flex:1``` and ```height: "100%"``` and that didn't work. Dimensions are working fine in both cases, partially open state as well as full open. You can check the working example given and if it's not behaving the way it should do let me know.

Comment: The thing I'm referring to is, when it's open, it's scrollable, despite being empty. That's due to the height of the modal being set to the entire screen's height, when the modal's height is not full screen.

Comment: Just noticed. Fixed. Do check out.